# Making a movement function for 2d unity game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So basically im programming a 2d game in unity using c# and i made a movement function as follows:

```
void PlayerMove(){
    movementX = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");

    transform.position += new Vector3(movementX, 0f, 0f) * Time.deltaTime * MovementSpeed;

}
```

then i call it in update() and this worked before but now that i got on my laptop using only the laptop keyboard it wont work, and i dont think its the laptop sending the keys weird or something like that since services like what key am i pressing works. Does anyone know what im doing wrong ive looked through it and im not getting any compiler errors.

Comment: did you try "A" and "D" instead of arrow-key? It only depends on the Input Mapping in Unity.

Comment: Yea ive tried using Input.GetKey("a"); too forexample and nothing seems to be working very well but im gonna double check

Comment: In the top left of unity there should be a settings page for input.  Since you're getting input via the horizontal axis, you should make sure the input keys for the horizontal axis are actually set.

Comment: @RyanR Unfortunately it seems like the settings are correct

Comment: Simple debug tip: Have you tried printing the value of `movementX` (with Debug.Log) and the value of `transform.position` to see what value you get or if that code is even run at all?

Comment: Are you sure that `PlayerMove()` is called? Try do add some debug logs. Code seams to be fine.